# Rails 4: How to use form_for and partials

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, form-for, partials

I am newbie ruby programmer and I´m suffering this error

This is part of my "new" form to create new "Subasta" objects

```
<%= form_for @subasta, url: {action: "crear"} do |s| %>
<%= s.label :precioinicial, 'Precio inicial' %>
<%= s.number_field :precioinicial,  class: "form-control", in: 1...10000 %>
<%= render :partial => "puja_minima", :locals=>{:s=>s} %>
```

This "new" form has a partial with another Subasta´s field

```
<%= s.label :puja_minima, 'La puja empezará por' %>
<%= s.number_field :puja_minima,  class: "form-control", in: 0...10000, disabled: true %>
```

The problem is the field 'puja_minima' doesn`t reachs the controller and it´s necessary:

```
validates :puja_minima, presence: true
```

The error is:

> The form contains 2 errors.
>   * Puja minima La puja mínima no debe estar vacía

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have **`disabled :true`** on your **`puja_minima`** field,make it as **`false`**.

```
<%= s.number_field :puja_minima,  class: "form-control", in: 0...10000, disabled: false %>
```

**OR**

Even just like this

```
<%= s.number_field :puja_minima,  class: "form-control", in: 0...10000 %>
```

**Update**

As you want it to be **`non-editable`**,use **`:readonly => true`**.

```
<%= s.number_field :puja_minima,  class: "form-control", in: 0...10000, :readonly => true %>
```

Comment: Don´t wanna that field to be editable. It´s a calculated field

Comment: Thanks Pavan, works for me! But I don´t include "disabled: false". For what it´s useful? <%= s.number_field : puja_minima,  class: "form-control", in: 0...10000, :readonly => true %>

Comment: @Marino You can neglect the `disabled : false`. I will update my answer.

Answer (score 0):

There's nothing wrong with the partial - the input is disabled.

Disabled inputs aren't submitted to the controller.

Comment: How do you avoid editing a input field and submits to the controller? Do you have any example?

Comment: If it's not editable, why rely on the form? You could set it in the controller.  Alternatively, also submit a hidden field containing the value.